# Setting up working files for 18/1 large format print

Tags: print-design, resolution

A client asked me to design a bill in a huge format. The printing company sent me a data sheet with the following information:

- Format: 18/1 (split in 4)
- End-scale: 3560mm x 2520mm
- Data-scale: 594mm x 420mm
- Resolution: 300dpi

I'm not sure how I should go on with this. Does it mean I have to design in a format that is 3560mm x 2520mm / 300dpi and then split it in 4 parts -
or do I have to design in 594mm x 420mm / 300dpi, split it in 4 parts and they will resize it to the actual size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working with Germans? Those wacky Germans use this 18/1 format.

Here is a link (in german naturlich) but with pictures that should give you an idea what they're talking about. https://www.maxxprint.de/posterdruck-plakatdruck/18-1-megaposter.html

But anyway: you should prepare the file with dimensions 594mm x 420mm in 300 dpi.
Then they will blow it up to 3560mm x 2520mm  with 50 dpi.

The difference between 420 not uspcaling to 2520 is the few mm needed for overlap when they will glue the poster.

Cutting the artwork in 4 is on the printing side so you should only be aware to not put in those line anything important because that can end up looking like this:
[image]

Yes, it's a fake but it show what to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Those proportions don't really make sense, unless one has a border or bleed and the other doesn't. Is it a billboard? Maybe source art is 300 dpi and they scale it up at lower resolution? The 18/1 doesn't make sense with these 2 proportions, and 594 doesn't fit equally into 3560 so they are not multiples of each other.

I would make your art 594mm x 420mm at 300 dpi with 4 vertical divisions (4 adjacent art boards will work) and place your vector design in there.

Save a version like that and save a version 600% that (594 x 600 = 356,400)

Ask them to be more clear next time. I'm kind of experienced and I never heard of data scale, and the proportion 18/1 or 18/4 does not equal the other proportions or their relational proportion.

By the way your art better be vector to blow up this big. If there is photographic content the photos will need to start at least 3600 px.